# Checking if string is like another in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

In rails is there a way of doing something like the following...

```
if @var == "string%"
```

The % meaning that there can be anything at the end of the string but as long as it starts with "string" it will return true.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is String#start_with?

http://rubydoc.info/docs/ruby-core/1.9.2/String#start_with%3F-instance_method

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regexp match:

```
if @var =~ /^string/ then
 ...
end
```

Comment: I know, but old habits die hard :)

Answer (score 2):

Ruby has you covered.

```
@var.start_with?('string')
```

As documented here: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001179

Answer (score 1):

```
if @var =~ /^string/
```

The `=~` indicates a regular expression match.

Alternatively you can do this:

```
if @var.include?("string")
```

but this means 'string' is anywhere in the string, not just at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if @var.start_with?("string")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'string'.match(/ring/i)
```

If you have a variable:

```
var = 'search'
'string'.match(/#{var}/i)
```

/i means case insensitive

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression (this one means that `@var` has to start with "string"):

```
if @var =~ /^string/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning on doing an ActiveRecord query with this,

```
SomeModel.where("column LIKE ?", "string%")
```